# Como pegar ou manipular dados dentro subscribe - Angular

Tags: json, angular, api, typescript, front-end

Infelizmente não consigo, mesmo dentro do subscribe, percorrer a variavel fixtures$
Consigo enviar os dados para o html e mostrar na tabela.
Porem preciso manipular os dados para salvar no banco ja no proprio 
".component".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 for (var i = 0; i < this.fixtures$.length; i++) {
            this.fixtures$[i].name = this.fixture$[i].id +' '+ this.fixtures[i].name 
            }
```

Não deu certo tambem.

Após varias e varias tentativas, consegui fazer funcionar com o código abaixo;
//service

```
    getFixtures(): Observable<any> {
      return this._http.get(this.baseUrl)
     .pipe(map(response => response));
  }
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
this.simpleBet.getFixtures().subscribe(
  data => {
    this.fixtures$ = data.data;
    this.fixtures$.forEach(x =>

       console.log(this.fixtures$, x)

       )
       for (var i = 0; i < this.fixtures$.length; i++) {
       console.log( this.fixtures$[i].name = this.fixtures$[i].id +' '+ this.fixtures$[i].name[i]) 
        } 
  },
  error => {
    this.errorMessage = `${error.status}: ${JSON.parse(error.error).message}`;
  }
);
```

}

Comment: Da uma olhada na aba network que ele está retornando os dados do seu backend corretamente. e coloca o código invés de imagem https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas

Comment: Entao, como eu disse, consigo enviar para lá, mas por exemplo gostaria de pegar os dados da Fixture$ fazer um for e ir salvando esses dados no banco porem, se eu colocar um console .log por exemplo na variavel fixtures$ ela esta como undefined, sobre a imagem é pq eu ja tinha elas e a visualização do codigo esta perfeita, por isso as fotos.

Comment: vc está dando um get de um endpoint da uma olhada que esse endpoint está retornando os dados corretos. Da uma olhada no link que enviei pq vc não deve usar imagens invés de código.

Comment: Sim, sei que estou recebendo os dados do endpoint, mas como ainda sou inexperiente em Angular eu não consigo manipular ele  ou saber a forma correta de como fazer isso, me falaram que não consigo pq ele é assincrono e tenho que realizar o for dentro do subcribe, tentei diversas maneiras olhando em outros post, mas não compreendi o que estou fazendo de errado. por gentileza se puder me dar um norte ficarei grato msm.

Comment: Ficaria mais facil te auxiliar se você tivesse colocado o código ao invés de colocar prints de códigos. O problema parece estar na service, remova o `pipe` de lá, e modifique o retorno da função `getFixtures` para `Observable<Fixture[]>` para testar, coloque um console.log de data dentro do subscribe da função que chama a `getFixtures`, poste aqui os resultados.

Comment: Ainda não acredito que ajudaria bem mais neste caso, sendo que vc pode visualizar do mesmo jeito ou melhor, mas sobre a questão eu agradeço muito pelas dicas,Imagino que o erro estava sendo no retorno do service pelo que vi, eu estava esperando um array, só que ao invés disso retornava um outro objeto.
vlw.